# Why are my plots not appearing on a shiny app using rmarkdown and flexdashboard?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, r-markdown, flexdashboard

When I first run my app (locally through RStudio or hosted on shinyapps.io), most of the times the plots show just fine, but disappear when I reload the page or resize the window. There are also times when the plots don’t even show on start and I have to rerun the app multiple times to make them appear.
My co-dev tried the same on his computer, with similarly inconsistent results.

Things I’ve tried:

- Using plotly instead of ggplot2.
- Limiting plot size to, say, 300x300 ou 10x10 px to check if it’s not a performance problem due to the size of the PNGs shiny renders as plots.
- Using rmarkdown::render_delayed so shiny wouldn’t have to load all plots at once.
  Those made no difference.

Could someone shed a light on the issue? Does anyone else have problems with plots on flexdashboard?

You can check a minimum example of the problem on https://ecology-app-test.shinyapps.io/minimum_example/ and the code on https://github.com/NHohl/ShinyEcology/blob/master/Minimum_Example.Rmd
Please try to load multiple times to see if/when the plots fail to show.
I have a more complete version that doesn’t use flexdashboards and works just fine (but the layout is a mess): https://nathalia--hohl.shinyapps.io/ecologia-interativa/

The package versions I’m using:

- R v. 4.2.0
- Rstudio v. 2022.02.1
- rmarkdown v. 2.14
- shiny v. 1.7.1
- flexdashboards v. 0.5.2
- ggplot2 v. 3.3.6
- plotly v. 4.10.0

Comment: The minimum example link is broken. It's really hard to help you solve such a broad issue "inconsistent display". When I'm confronted with similar issues, I start stripping down the page until I get to the line that causes the problem. With a smaller reproducible problem in hand, I come to SO for help. If I suspect a chuck of code is the culprit, I take that out the app and place it in a shiny basicPage() to see if I can reproduce the problem. I can take a look at a reproducible sample posted in SO.

Comment: Thank you for the tips on best practices. I could not isolate the line itself, but came to a conclusion after following other suggestions and will go back to using shiny itself instead of runtime:shiny on rmarkdown.